# Connection to Service Fabric Cluster Endpoint From Behind Corporate Proxy

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

I have created one Service Fabric Cluster but I am not able to connect to it's endpoint. Currently I am behind Corporate Proxy so I think this is the reason to not get connected.As connection is working from my non proxy environment(Free Internet Environment).

I used the following command:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint mycluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000 -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint F45E63D80AE4AB2F6938CDD7DFC77E8E38D00CD7 -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue F45E63D80AE4AB2F6938CDD7DFC77E8E38D00CD7 -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

Error I am getting is :

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
>   WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
>   False
>   WARNING: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 40.117.45.185:19000
>   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint mycluster.westus.cloudap ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

I just would like to know, how to get connected to SF Cluster Endpoints from behind corporate proxy?

Help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Abjo

Comment: Ask your network admin.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ask corporate IT to allow outgoing tcp traffic at port 19000 to [Azure Data Center IP ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653).
2. Create a [VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to the [VNet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2016/10/05/azure-service-fabric-common-networking-scenarios/) that holds the VM Scaleset (of your cluster).
3. For release from VSTS, run a self hosted agent inside the VNet.